# How to figure out used JARs?

Tags: java

In a bigger project we might be using tons of JARs. How do I find out which JARs are being used by a certain module/package in the project (not the whole project). Any tool, technique,  etc?

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950642/how-to-analyse-which-jar-file-is-used-in-a-java-program

Comment: If you were to use Maven for dependency management, you could have a nice dependency graph with the Eclipse plugin

Comment: this question might also help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179858/how-to-find-which-jars-and-in-what-order-are-loaded-by-a-classloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bigger projects typically use a build tool like [maven](http://maven.apache.org) or [ant](http://ant.apache.org).  maven has the [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to list the dependencies for a particular project which you invoke by `mvn dependency:list`.  In case of ant, it depends on the way the build script is written.

Maybe you should give more details about your project environment and you may get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

The various code obfuscators, reducers etc can help.

Check out:

http://jarg.sourceforge.net/

http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/jax/

http://www.e-t.com/jshrink.html

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

http://www.fightingquaker.com/jaropt/

btw, this list was acquired from http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-programmer/34365/How-to-create-a-JAR-that-contains-only-the-class-files