# How to debug classpath command line option (-cp) for java executable?

Tags: java, debugging, command-line

I want to execute the java executable (Open JDK 11.0.2) on **Windows** from command line and I am not sure if I specify the class path option correctly, e.g.

```
java -cp "./foo_\*/*" -version
```

How can I print a list of all **files** that can be found by java on the given class path?

Is there something like

```
echo java -cp "./foo_\*/*"
```

or

```
java -debug -cp "./foo_\*/*" -version
```

Comment: You may find this question useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950642/how-to-analyse-which-jar-file-is-used-in-a-java-program

Answer (score 6):

Just simply add `-verbose:class`

See article here: https://dzone.com/articles/how-use-verbose-options-java there are also other options/flag to better debug it.

Comment: Goes into right direction. Still could not find out how I could include the file paths for the classes on windows.

Comment: If you want add multiple directories/regex then you have to seperate them with ";" on windows. Eg.java -cp "./foo;./foo2;/foox/*"

Comment: I mean that the -verbose:class option prints class names but not file names.

Comment: @Stefan: the `-verbose:class` prints both, e.g.: `[Loaded javax.swing.JTree from C:\etc\Java8\jre\lib\rt.jar]`

Comment: Not for me. Maybe this depends on the java version? I use Open JDK 11.0.2. Or unitl now I do not load any file... will try some more stuff.

Comment: Hm. Does seem to work with java 11. However, it seems that -verbose:class only prints the actually loaded files (?) and not all available files.